# Authentication with Azure Active Directory : WIF10201 Error

Tags: authentication, azure

I'm trying to add Azure Authentication to an existing website with Visual Studio 2013. It looks like this used to be a bit easier in 2012 but seems the recommended path for 2013 is to set this up when creating the project.

I created a new project with AAD (which works) to compare to the changes being made to the project I need to add authentication to. I copied the authentication classes and config settings but it still seems like there is something wrong in web.config:

For **AppSettings** I have:

```
<add key="ida:FederationMetadataLocation" value="https://login.windows.net/_____/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" />
<add key="ida:Realm" value="https://AADPath/Application" />
<add key="ida:AudienceUri" value="https://AADPath/Application" />
```

For **System.identityModel** I have:

```
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <issuerNameRegistry type="RegistryClassPath, ProjectName" />
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="https://AADPath/Application"/>
      </audienceUris>
      <securityTokenHandlers>
```

For **system.identityModel.services** I have:

```
<federationConfiguration>
  <cookieHandler requireSsl="true" />
  <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true"
                issuer="https://login.windows.net/AADPath/wsfed" 
                realm="https://AADPath/Application" 
                requireHttps="true" />
```

When I run the site, I'm redirected to the login page as I expect but after logging in I'm presented with the **WIF10201: No valid key mapping found for securityToken** error.

Comment: They really botched up the Authentication wizardry in VS 2013. Forcing you to start a new project to set or change is just wrong.

Comment: I thought that was kind of odd also. I kept notes for every step I took so hopefully I can turn that into a blog post or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not the configuration but rather I didn't copy the data from the embedded database to the existing project. All seems to be working now.

Comment: I remember hitting this one as well......sorry I forgot or I would have mentioned. Again, another problem, I didn't figure out as well until a deployment. They automagically create a database and that you are not even aware of until you deploy and figure out what your app is not working. THANKS Entity Framework guys......you should NEVER EVER create a database without telling me.

Comment: Yea, that always spooks me a bit when something does something like that on your behalf.